# How to format space between operators C++ Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, formatting

What I am trying to acheive is to find if there exists a way to format the space between the operators in C++, Visual Studio (2012 in my case).

For example writing the following line of code in C#:

```
int number=10;
```

Then hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in C# is formatting the code to:

```
int number = 10;
```

As it can be seen there were added spaces between the equal operator (`=`). When I try to format the code in the same Visual Studio, but for C++, is added indentation only on branches, but the space between operators remains the same.

Is it possible to achieve the same functionality for C++?

**Edit**

This is what I see in C/C++ > Formatting:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I no longer have VS 2012, but for VS 2013 and 2015 you can do the following (I imagine it hasn't changed a whole lot):

Check Tools > Options... > Text Editor > C/C++ > Formatting > Spacing, and find "Spacing for operators"

There you should have a number of settings, like "insert spaces before and after binary operators"

In your specific case, you'll want to make sure "Insert spaces around assignment operators" is selected.

Afterwards, auto-format should take care of it for you.

Edit: I was able to check a machine that had VS 2012, and indeed there is no option like this ([msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6hx0kx(v=vs.110).aspx)). Sounds like you need to upgrade if you want this ability.

Comment: I am sorry to hear, but glad to know. Thank you for confirmation!

Comment: Had the same issue with C# in Visual Studio 2022, where the option is named "Insert space before and after binary operators". This answer was the clue I needed :)