# How to fix Visual Studio 2019 C# spacing for MyMethod ()

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Whenever I do "Ctrl + k + d" the method "()" gets separated by space with its method name like this
var x = MyMethod_();

The underscore shows the space.

Comment: Are you using an editorconfig file? Or maybe some other custom setting in the options dialog?

Comment: [Options dialog box: Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-csharp-formatting) • [Code style preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you auto format code in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755942/) and [How to format space between operators C++ Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964033/) and [Can Visual Studio 2017 remove space around = like Vs2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653339/) and [Turn off auto formatting in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737222/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit it when searching for Formatting in the options menu.
Then go to `Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > Spacing`
Scroll down to Set spacing for method calls and disable "Insert spacing between method name and its opening parenthesis".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can update the relevant settings here:

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > Spacing > Set other spacing options

Note, your `.editorconfig` file (if exists) might override the local settings configured on that page which only apply to your machine.

It would be best to configure it in the `.editorconfig` file which will be common to all engineers who use the repository.